# Fail to deploy rail app to heroku (error while installing linecache19 (0.5.12)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to upload my rail app to Heroku. I'm using Ruby 1.9.3.
The app can be deployed okay on my local machine.

```
 An error occurred while installing linecache19 (0.5.12), and Bundler cannot continue.
   Make sure that `gem install linecache19 -v '0.5.12'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
```

I've tried entering this line to the Gemfile

```
gem 'linecache19', :git => 'git://github.com/mark-moseley/linecache'
```

But it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Can someone please advise ? Thank you in advance for the help.
p.s.: Really sorry for the newbie question, I'm pretty new at Ruby on Rails development.

Below is my complete Gemfile

---

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

# for Heroku deployment - as described in Ap. A of ELLS book
group :development, :test do
 gem 'sqlite3'
 gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
end
group :production do
 gem 'pg'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
 gem 'therubyracer'              
 gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
 gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
 gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
gem 'haml'

gem 'linecache19', :git => 'git://github.com/mark-moseley/linecache'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`linecache19` is a gem used for debugging purposes. There is no need for it in production, so you should be excluding it from the gems used in production.

Add it to the `:development, :test` group you already have toward the top of your file, `bundle`, and re-deploy.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
  gem 'linecache19', :git => 'git://github.com/mark-moseley/linecache'
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Deefour, I've moved it to the development, test group and then I execute 
    bundle install
    git push heroku master
but I still receive the same error. Could you please advise ? - Thank you

Comment: Did you commit your new `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` to heroku? Is the push to heroku successful? Aside from you forgetting to commit your changes or doing a bad push, I see no reason why the deploy would try to build `linecache19` again.

Comment: In addition, you may also need to set a config flag to not install test or development gems: `$ heroku config:add BUNDLE_WITHOUT="test development" --app app_name` More info here: http://blog.johnfnixon.com/using-rails-3x-with-heroku

Comment: @Deefour Thank you for your help, it's working now after I recommit everything and redeploy to heroku.